# How to fix defaults for other predefined formats in memoir class with trim marks

Tags: errors, memoir, alignment, trimbox

I'm trying to make a pdf for publishing.
Using different sizes for stock paper and actual page size, I get crazy layout. Trim signs do not correspond page limits.

Here is my Minimal Failing Example:

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}

% stock papre size A3
\stockaiii
% page size small royal
\pagemsmallroyalvo

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{showlocs}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-15]

\end{document}
```

### [image: smallroyalvo not trimmed properly]

**EDIT:**
Actually, I tried

```
\checkandfixthelayout
```

And I get

```
Class memoir Error: \spinemargin (109.26999pt) and/or \textwidth (341.0pt) 
and/or \foremargin (164.02501pt) are too large 
for \paperwidth (443.86299pt) by 170.432pt.
```

So default calculations are not working and this command doesn't fix anything. That's what I expected to avoid: calculating all by myself...

Comment: Try adding `\checkandfixthelayout` after setting the sizes.  That will report several layout problems that you need to fix.

Comment: You haven't adjusted the size of the type block and it is too large for the page size.

Comment: Memoir does not recalculate any of the margins after the class have been loaded, if you change something, you need to adjust manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the stock and paper size, but have not touched the page layout, which is designed for US letter and doesn't fit into the small page size you're working with.

I don't know which page layout you want to use, so this is just an example. You can obviously substitute the layout you desire.

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}

% stock papre size A3
\stockaiii % 420*297mm
% page size small royal
\pagemsmallroyalvo% 234*156mm
\semiisopage
\setpagecc{\paperheight}{\paperwidth}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{showlocs}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-15]

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting layout]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the kind of mistake I expected I did.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to get the calculations done by defaults, I found I can first set the predefined size for the (trimmed) page (e.g. **`msmallroyalvopaper`**) as class option and then move stock paper size to bigger (e.g. **`stockaiv`**):

```
% pass the predefined paper size as option
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper,showtrims]{memoir}

% set larger stock paper
\stockaiv

% optional, placing the trimmed page centered on the stock
\setpagecc{\paperheight}{\paperwidth}{*}  

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{showlocs}
\begin{document}

\kant[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Then, we can even move away from predefined margins and have the text block adjusted within the page format

```
[...]
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{18mm}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout
[...]
```